# XML error - markup root element

Tags: android, xml

I'm having the following XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" >

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Error msg : "The markup in the documentfollowing the root element is well - performed.
All tags are closed, what could cause this?

Comment: Try ctrl + shift + F to your xml code which will format the code and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ctrl` + `shift` + `F` to your xml code which will format the code and try again after cleaning the project.it will work.